# LDAP Authentication with sAMAccountName and Password

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently developing a web application where the users can log in with their account name.
All users are part of a Microsoft Domain.

My User has following attributes:

```
CN: "Test Account"
displayName: "Test Account"
distinguishedName: "CN=Test Account,OU=Users,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=com"
sAMAccountName: "test.account"
userPrincipalName: "test.account@company.com"
```

Currently, I'm trying to bind using this code:

```
$link = @ldap_connect($server);
@ldap_bind($link, $username, $password);
```

The problem is that ldap_bind will fail if the displayName is unequal to the sAMAccountName.

So how can I bind using password and sAMAccountName, without knowing the displayName/cn?

Comment: My user got also the **name** attribute which holds the value **Test Account**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592).

It shows how to authenticate a user with any unique attribute from the LDAP-Entry without knowing the DN of the user.

Beware that you will need a user with read-privileges on the LDAP as AD doesn't allow anonymous binding. And you'll want to use an ldaps-connection, therefore instead of `ldap_connect($server, $port)` use `ldap_connect('ldaps://ldap.server.tld:port')`.